# Error: while Importing data into Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, sqlbulkcopy

I wanted to unload from one database(production) and reload into another database(QA) in Redshift having exact same schema.

I issued S3 load command as following.

```
copy table(col1,col2,col3,col4) from 's3://<bucket_path>/<file_name>.gzip' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<your_key>;aws_secret_access_key=<your_secret>'  delimiter '|' gzip NULL AS 'null_string';
```

Got following error.

### ERROR:  Failed writing body (0 != XXX) Cause: Failed to inflateinvalid or incomplete deflate data. zlib error code: -3

```
  error:  Failed writing body (0 != XXX) Cause: Failed to inflateinvalid or incomplete deflate data. zlib error code: -3
  code:      9001
  context:   S3 key being read : s3://<some_s3_bucket>/<some_s3_bucket_file>
  query:     XXXXX
  location:  table_s3_scanner.cpp:355
  process:   query1_23 [pid=2008]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Looks like an error decompressing the gzip file.  How was the was the `gzip` file created? Can you download it and unzip it successfully?

Comment: Thank you  John!  Yes, you are correct. I had issue in gzip file itself and the file wasn't correct. I created different file with gzip and worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you are trying to use Gzip file during copy and it cannot read the file as a Gzip. 
 
If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.