# Failed to inflateinvalid or incomplete deflate data. zlib error code -3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to upload data on redshift using s3. The file from which data is to be copied is in csv format (say named users.csv). I run following command

```
    copy user.dimension_users from 's3://<bucket-name>/users.csv'
    credentials
 'aws_access_key_id=<access_key>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret_key>'gzip compupdate off region '<region>';
```

I execute this command from Workbench/J and get the following error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Failed writing body (0 != 173) Cause: Failed to inflateinvalid or incomplete deflate data. zlib error code: -3
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Failed writing body (0 != 173) Cause: Failed to inflateinvalid or incomplete deflate data. zlib error code: -3
  code:      9001
  context:   S3 key being read : s3://<bucket_name>/users.csv
  query:     151550
  location:  table_s3_scanner.cpp:360
  process:   query0_124_151550 [pid=8795]
  -----------------------------------------------;
1 statement failed.
```

Comment: I had similar problem in past, did you get chance to look into it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906216/error-while-importing-data-into-redshift

Comment: @RedBoy Yes. I am following that question. Can you please tell me how did you find that the issue was with gzip and how did you resolve it. Thanks

Comment: I downloaded manually the file from `S3`, when I checked, the file was not `gzipped`, instead it was plain text file. Hence Redshift was failing.

Comment: You could simple remove the `gzip` from your query it should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Failed to inflate invalid or incomplete deflate data.

This is basically telling you there is a problem with the compression of the file you are trying to load using the COPY statement. Possible causes:

- The file is incomplete or corrupt
- The file is not actually compressed
  using gzip (i.e. it is uncompressed or compressed in a format other
  than gzip)